# Truncating array in lowdb

Tags: node.js, lodash

I am using [lowdb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lowdb), which is built on lodash.

In lodash, I could use the following to truncate my array to the first or last `n` items:

```
myarr = _.take(myarr, 5) // or
myarr = _.takeRight(myarr, 5)
```

With lowdb, I might write an update as:

```
db.get('items').push(new_item).write()
```

However, I am unable to truncate this:

```
db.get('items').push(new_item).take(10).write() // Will ignore the 'take'
```

This works when retrieving a value:

```
db.get('items').take(10).value() // Contains only last 10 items
```

How can I properly truncate my array in the 'database'?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this can be done on a single chain, but it can definitely be done.

```
let items = db.get('items').push(new_item).takeRight(10).value();
db.set('items', items).write();
```

Or if you want a "one-liner"

```
db.set('items', db.get('items').push(new_item).takeRight(10).value()).write();
```

By the way, if you are using `push` you want to `takeRight` not `take`. Push appends items at the end of the array. If you want new items at the beginning of the array you need to use `unshift` and then you can use `take`.